# Set up build task in vscode with global tsc parameters

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsc

We have the following project structure

```
+-- views
    +-- viewXXX
        +-- ts
        ¦    +-- controller.ts
        ¦    +-- helper.ts
        ¦    +-- ... (*.ts)
        +-- viewXXX.ctrl.js // this is the desired output file
        +-- viewXXX.ctrl.map.js
        +-- viewXXX.html
```

We are trying to configure a task in VSCode that allows to compile following this structure...

```
// A task runner that calls the Typescript compiler (tsc)
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "args": [
        "-t",
        "es5",
        "-m",
        "commonjs",
        "--sourceMap",
        "--out",
        "${fileDirname}.ctrl.js",
        // "--filesGlob", missing
        "${fileDirname}\\ts\\*.ts"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

And we are not able to make it work because there is no **--filesGlob** parameter, or any other way to pass a ***regex*** to compile many files. **Any other approach that allows this workflow??**

Comment: There's no way around that. Just write a grunt/gulp file that uses `glob` or something. [See the issue related.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1927)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, here is a working solution :

1. Use the following package.json at the root of your project directory

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

2. `npm install`
3. In the .vscode/task.json :

```js
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "gulp",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "default",
            // Make this the default build command.
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "silent"
        }
    ]
}
```

4. In the gulpfile.js at the root of your project directory :

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var views = [
  "views/view1",
  "views/view2"  
];

function buildView(viewBasePath) {
    var finalName = viewBasePath.split('/').pop();

    var tsResult = gulp.src(viewBasePath + '/ts/*.ts') 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts({
            "module": "commonjs",
            "target": "es5",
            "out": finalName + '.ctrl.js'
        }));

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(viewBasePath));
}

gulp.task('default', function () {
    for(var i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
        buildView(views[i]);   
    }
});
```

And if you want to build, use the combination CTRL+SHIFT+B or install a watch in the gulpfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tsconfig.json in the root directory of your project :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "out": "${fileDirname}.ctrl.js"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "${fileDirname}\\ts\\*.ts"
  ]
}
```

And then set the directory of the tsconfig.json via the "-p" argument :

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

And finally, launch the task runner via CTRL+SHIFT+B.

Comment: Is not `filesGlob` an exclusive parameter for the atom-typescript plugin? Will it work on vscode?

Comment: Apologies for that, you're right. But you have 2 solutions instead : 1. Use the following package to support filesGlob https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-glob 2. Use "exclude" node.

Comment: I have tried that with this tsconfig `{
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "command": "tsconfig",
 "isShellCommand": true,
 "showOutput": "silent",
 "args": ["${workspaceRoot}"],
 "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}` and also tried toe `"args":"."`, none of them worked.